# How can i transfer app data to from iPhone to Macbook?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

I have download a full courseware on my iPhone Udemy App. I want to transfer these course materials from phone to Macbook. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

It seems people are not getting the point. I do not want to download it again altogether  *when i have it on my iPhone* (**already** downloaded). I want to view those videos of the courseware on a mac.

Comment: Did you check the Udemy support site?

Comment: https://support.udemy.com/customer/portal/articles/1497781 is all i could find which does not answer me.

Comment: See the answer from Jaime Santa Cruz then, it offers ways to try to get the video from the iPhone backup on your computer or access the content of your iPhone from your computer directly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Udemy support site](https://support.udemy.com/customer/portal/articles/1497278-can-i-download-a-course-to-my-computer-):

> If you're using the Udemy mobile app, you can save courses to your
>   device for offline viewing. Unfortunately, courses cannot be
>   downloaded to a PC or Mac unless the instructor has made a lecture
>   available.
>
> If an instructor has enabled downloading, you'll see the lecture under
>   the Supplemental Materials section to the right of the lecture. Click
>   on the second tab to check for any downloads:
>
> [image: udemy]
>
> If the lecture is not available to download, you can always send a
>   message to the instructor requesting that they enable downloading.
>   Some instructors are willing to make exceptions, but the final
>   decision is up to them

.

Comment: I have it downloaded on the iphone app but the question is how to get this from iphone to mac ? 

Under new scheme one is not allowed to download on PC

Comment: @nezam "courses cannot be downloaded to a PC or Mac unless the instructor has made a lecture available", so it might be best to contact your instructor.

Comment: You are not getting the point. I do not want to download it again altogether  when i have it on my iPhone (already downloaded). I want to view those videos of the courseware on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer in case I misunderstood you:

You can make a backup of your iOS device with iTunes to your computer (Mac or PC) and browse it, but from googling around it appears that you'll need an app to be able to extract anything from it.

I've found [this article](http://ojs.jdfsl.org/index.php/jdfsl/article/download/38/23) ("Exploring the iPhone Backup made by iTunes"), that identifies five categories of data inside of it:

> - SQLite3 database files;
> - Plain text plist files;
> - Binary plist files;
> - Multimedia and text files.
> - Non-standard data file

Maybe some of the data your looking for is stored as multimedia files and is easily extracted.

If that is not the case, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157833/how-do-i-transfer-a-single-app-with-data-from-one-iphone-to-another) talks about iExplorer being able to browse the phone itself; there's [this other app](http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/) that claims to do the same for free (on the backup, apparently).

I haven't tried any of them, so I can't vouch for them.

---

I've just downloaded and tried [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/), a free tool that lets you browse iOS devices as if they were external disks. I don't have Udemy installed but it seems very likely that if there is anything usable inside the app you will be able to copy it to your Mac with it.